# D3 bar chart not showing first element in array

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm working on the first set of D3 tutorials (found [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)) and have run into a problem where the first item of the data array doesn't appear. The border i have placed on each data div element indicates that essentially that first entry has "collapsed" into a line up the top. Is there an explanation as to why this is happening? How can I fix this?

My HTML, CSS and JS has been put onto [codepen](https://codepen.io/libbyB/pen/LxdeNm/) to view and edit.

Thanks in advance!

Isolated JS:

```
var data = [10, 23, 14, 5, 6, 6, 6, 22, 17 ]; 

d3.select(".project") 
  .selectAll(".project__bar-chart")
    .data(data) 
  .enter()
  .append("div") 
    .attr("class", "project__bar-chart")
    .style("width", function(d) {return d + "rem";}) 
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
```

Comment: Remove the `<div>` inside your `<div class="project">`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this in your HTML:

```
<div class="project">
  <div class="project__bar-chart"></div>
</div>
```

Thus, when you do:

```
d3.select(".project").selectAll(".project__bar-chart")
```

You are selecting one previously existing `<div>` in your `selectAll`, and your "enter" selection will have one element less.

Solution: remove the div with class `project__bar-chart`:

```
<div class="project">
    //look Ma, no div
</div>
```

Here is your Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgKxXG?editors=1010

And here is a Stack snippet:

```js
var data = [10, 23, 14, 5, 6, 6, 6, 22, 17 ]; //The data that we're working with

d3.select(".project") //bring our focus to the container containing this class
  .selectAll(".project__bar-chart")
    .data(data) //the data is in line 1 
  .enter()
  .append("div") // Shove the data (defined in line 1) into the Div in the HTML
    .attr("class", "project__bar-chart")
    .style("width", function(d) {return d + "rem";}) 
//we're inserting a function in this style attribute to make sure that the width of the div reflects the value given. 
    .text(function(d) {return d;}) //this is what it will look like
```

```css
.project {
  color: black;
    font: 1rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: .1rem:;
    text-align: right;
}

.project__bar-chart {
    background: #be3c3c;
    border: 1px solid #802828
    }
```

```html
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The doc you linked is also very helpful.